# Getting JDBC drivers compatibility issue. java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06413: Connection not open

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am getting below exception with Oracle JDBC [ojdbc14_g.jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-10201-088211.html) drivers:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06413: Connection not open.
```

My Oracle version is:

[image]

My machine and server details are:

[image]

*I am able to connect to production DB from my development environment, but after installing application in production server my application is unable to connect to locally installed database. I am getting above said exception.*

Below is my connection URL:

```
jdbc:oracle:oci8:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE
```

Comment: Try to replace oci8 with thin. JDBC over (native) OCI require some knowledge and experience. You have to install and configure Oracle client 1st.

Comment: @ibre5041 please provide me detailed explanation, I am not much aware of JDBC over (native) OCI

Comment: see installation section http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/instclnt.htm

Comment: @ibre5041 please post your first comment in answer section, this was the solution.

Comment: thanks a ton, i really got stuck in this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace oci8 with thin. JDBC over (native) OCI require some knowledge and experience. You have to install and configure Oracle client 1st.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/instclnt.htm